# Check if DHCP scope exists

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, dhcp, powershell-4.0

I'm making scripts to automate Windows Server 2012 configuration in Powershell 4.0. Right now I managed to create DHCP scopes, exclusions and reservations but I want to test/check DHCP scopes before they are made.

What I mean is that I first want to test or check if a DHCP scope already exists before running the function I've written (to make a new scope). If the scope already exists I want the script to skip the function. If not I want it to run the function to create the scope.
The specific part of testing/checking I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Get-DhcpServerv4Scope`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590670.aspx) for listing the existing scopes and filter the list via `Where-Object` (alias `?`) for the name or ID you want to verify:

```
if (-not (Get-DhcpServerv4Scope | ? { $_.Name -eq 'foo' })) {
  Add-DhcpServerv4Scope ...
}
```

or

```
if (-not (Get-DhcpServerv4Scope | ? { $_.ScopeId -eq '192.168.23.0' })) {
  Add-DhcpServerv4Scope ...
}
```

You can wrap the check in a custom function

```
function Test-DhcpServerv4Scope {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='name')]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='name')]
    [string]$Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='id')]
    [string]$ScopeId
  )

  $p = $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Keys

  [bool](Get-DhcpServerv4Scope | Where-Object {
    $_.$p -eq $MyInvocation.BoundParameters[$p]
  })
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if (-not (Test-DhcpServerv4Scope -Name 'foo')) {
  Add-DhcpServerv4Scope ...
}
```

or like this:

```
if (-not (Test-DhcpServerv4Scope -ScopeId '192.168.23.0')) {
  Add-DhcpServerv4Scope ...
}
```

Replace `*-DhcpServerv4Scope` with `*-DhcpServerv6Scope` if you're dealing with IPv6 scopes.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to clear a little bit out what the .BoundParameters.Keys stands for but I'll look that up myself. I guess that it's possible to get the -name and -scopid parameters from a variable that I'll get via another Cmdlet. Just to make it a little bit more flexible and I don't have to hard code these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check remotly, like via a CimSession, you could get a quick boolean answer like this :

```
If((get-dhcpserverv4scope -CimSession $CimSession).ScopeId -contains "1.10.20.0" ) 
{... Then do this}
else { do this }
```